# Sophisticated Table Header Latex

Tags: tables, multicol

I have a table which I want to transform it into Latex Code

[image]

But, I am beginner in Latex, thus, the header of this table is hard 
for me to write it in Latex.

Comment: This table header is not difficult reproduce, however, what you do so far? Do you have any code concern it? And how wide can table to be?

Comment: I relate *sophisticated* to simplicity and elegance, this is more like screaming for attention with a pimped out car.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  questions look like "do this for me" ... For my exercise I reproduce part of above table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Line segment}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

    \begin{document}
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{|>{\bfseries}c|L|c|c|c|}
    \hline
\multirowcell{5}{\thead{No.}}
    &   \multirowcell{5}{\thead{Questions}}
        &   \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\thead{Type of line}}    \\
        \cline{3-5}
    &   &   \rothead{Line}
            &   \rothead{Line segment}
                &   \rothead{Ray}                       \\
    \hline
Q1  &   Which of the following are straight?
        &   Yes &   Yes &   Yes                         \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{document}
```

where I omit coloring of first two table rows. Above code gives:

[image]
Now you can answer yourself? Do I really need colored the first two table rows? Do be table nicer without vertical lines and column headers separated from other rows with rules provided by package `booktabs`?

Educative is to see ["Wie Tabellen eigentlich aussehen sollten?"](http://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/)

Anyway, I try to give you a starting point, from where you can proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution, hopefully, satisfies @Johannes_B's criteria for simplicity and elegance. :-)

Note that I use no vertical bars and only one horizontal rule (at the bottom of the table). I also don't gratuitously require readers of the table to crane their necks just so that they can read the subheader cells.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry} % choose page and margin sizes
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\bfseries}l X C{1cm} C{1.75cm} C{1cm} }
\rowcolor{lightgray} No. & \textbf{Questions} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Type of line}} \\[1ex]
\rowcolor{lightgray} & & \bfseries Line & \bfseries Line Segment & \bfseries Ray \\
\addlinespace
Q1 & Which of the following are straight? & Yes & Yes & Yes \\
Q2 & Which of the following are part of a line? & No & Yes & Yes \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks a bit better :-)